# ImageClassification.Fit - IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, ml.net

I've used the Fit method to train my model, that's generating exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array".

I've created one library .Net Core 3.1 and a UnitTesting (.Net Core 3.1) where the UnitTesting call a property "Training()" in my library.

This code refer at the example in [Tutorial: Automated visual inspection using transfer learning with the ML.NET Image Classification API](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification-api-transfer-learning#use-the-model)

```
public void Training()
{
    MLContext mlc = new MLContext();

    try
    {
        IEnumerable<ImageData> images = LoadImagesFromDirectory(folder: AssetsRelativePath, useFolderNameAsLabel: true);
        IDataView imageData = mlc.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(images);
        IDataView shuffledData = mlc.Data.ShuffleRows(imageData);

        var preprocessingPipeline = mlc.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "Label", outputColumnName: "LabelAsKey")
            .Append(mlc.Transforms.LoadImages(outputColumnName: "Image", imageFolder: AssetsRelativePath, useImageType: false, inputColumnName: "ImagePath"));

        IDataView preProcessedData = preprocessingPipeline.Fit(shuffledData).Transform(shuffledData);

        TrainTestData trainSplit = mlc.Data.TrainTestSplit(data: preProcessedData, testFraction: 0.3);
        TrainTestData validationTestSplit = mlc.Data.TrainTestSplit(trainSplit.TestSet);

        IDataView trainSet = trainSplit.TrainSet;
        IDataView validationSet = validationTestSplit.TrainSet;
        IDataView testSet = validationTestSplit.TestSet;

        var trainingPipeline = mlc.Model.ImageClassification(
               featuresColumnName: "Image", 
               labelColumnName: "LabelAsKey", 
               arch: ImageClassificationEstimator.Architecture.ResnetV2101,
               epoch: 100, 
               batchSize: 10, 
               testOnTrainSet: false, 
               metricsCallback: (metrics) => Logger.Debug(metrics), 
               validationSet: validationSet,
               reuseTrainSetBottleneckCachedValues: true, 
               reuseValidationSetBottleneckCachedValues: true, 
               disableEarlyStopping: false
            )
            .Append(mlc.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));


        ITransformer trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainSet);
    }
    catch{

    }
}
```

I receive an exception: [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://i.ibb.co/n8Ws9TH/Eccezione-ml-net.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that some of your images fail to load? Maybe try, prior to training, to save  `trainSet` to disk (as a text or binary file), and see if it continues to throw?

Basically, my suspicion is that the data itself is corrupted, and the first time you scan through it, you immediately discover this.

Comment: I've removed the property Append in ImageClassification (.Append(mlc.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel")) and the process work without error. But now, the result is correct?